# Accessing objects inside array

Tags: arrays, angular, object, typescript, multidimensional-array

[image]

I am having trouble accessing elements of an array.
When I print the array using :

```
console.log(MyArray);
```

I get the console as shown in the image.

I have got the data of this array from an API.
I don't want to access it inside the callback but eventually use the data to plot markers on map.

I am stuck at this.

```
     private MyArray: any[] = [];
     ngOnInit() {
        this.httpservice.getdata().subscribe
        (data=>
        {this.MyArray.push(data);});

     console.log(MyArray[0]);//I am trying to access it here

    var mapProp = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850),
      zoom: 10,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), 
     mapProp);

    var markerarray: any[] = [];



    //I want to eventually access the data here

    for (i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
      markerarray[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(MyArray[0][i].latitude, MyArray[i]
     [i].longitude),          //In this line
        title: MyArray[1][i].name,  //and this
        map: map
      });


    }
```

My httpservice.ts looks like:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Response, RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http'

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {

    constructor(private hhtp: Http) { }
    getdata() {
        return this.hhtp.get('url').map((res: Response) => { //the url which I am using
            return res.json();
        })

    }

}
```

Comment: How do you try to access the elements?

Comment: @er-han For example ,if i want to access the name I use: console.log(MyArray[0][1].name). This is not working.

Comment: can you add the error log too?

Comment: @er-han  error_handler.js:54 EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:3:45 caused by: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

Comment: You haven't provided the code where you access it. The question is pointless in its current state. Most likely you can't access it with MyArray[0][1].name because you have race condition. getdata().subscribe... is asychronous. If you try to access it before the callback was triggered, MyArray will be empty. This is fundamental quality of async code. It doesn't have anything to do with arrays. This could be just a variable.

Comment: @estus Thankyou, I will update my question

Comment: Just a quick hint when debugging, try using `console.table` rather than `console.log` to have a quick view of tabular data.  I know this works in Chrome 57.*, Firefox 44.* and Safari 9.1.*.  I don't have access to IE.

Comment: Ok. You can't access it there. Because .subscribe... is async and hasn't received values yet. Do console.log inside .subscribe callback.

Comment: @estus But I want to access the data outside the callback. Is it possible to make that happen?

Comment: Why exactly do you need to do that? You're going the wrong way and it's not possible to say which one will be the right one without knowing the details.

Comment: @estus The data includes some longitude and latitude. I want to use that for plotting on the map. For that I need to access the data which I got from the http call.

Comment: How do you use this data? Where's the code that uses it? This all should be in your question, because this is highly relevant.

Comment: @estus Okay, I have updated my question.

Comment: Yes, the answers already explains that. The problem was in the definition of the problem. You cannot and you shouldn't get the array outside of .subscribe callback. Just put the code that depends on this array inside this callback. Not the cleanest way to do this, but it will work.

Comment: @estus Okay, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to access your array before the subscribe method has returned.

Modify ngOnInit() like this and try :

```
   private MyArray: any[] = [];
   ngOnInit() {
    var mapProp = {
           center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850),
           zoom: 10,
           mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), 
                  mapProp);

   var markerarray: any[] = [];
   this.httpservice.getdata().subscribe(
   (data)=>
   {
     this.MyArray.push(data);
     console.log(MyArray[0]);//Access it here

    //I want to eventually access the data here

    for (i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
      markerarray[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(MyArray[0][i].latitude, MyArray[i]
     [i].longitude),          //In this line
        title: MyArray[1][i].name,  //and this
        map: map
      });
    }  // end for
   });  // end subscribe
 } // end ngOninit
```

The browser console will show you the full data because if you see the tool tip across an image 'i' it will say 'Value below are evaluated just now'. It means that when you tried to access object within array while doing console, there was no object value within it.

Comment: Thankyou, but I eventually want to use it outside the callback. I have updated my question.

Comment: Is `for` loop where you want to access MyArray is within your ngOnit()?

Comment: Yes it is inside ng0nit().

Comment: Well. In that case `for` loop has to be within subscribe block. Or else it will run before MyArray has its data.

Comment: Updated my answer. please check that.

Answer (score -1):

When do you try to access the elements? If you try to access before the result from the service comes, MyArray would be still empty.

If you try accessing an element just after `data` comes, you should see it working:

```
private MyArray: any[] = [];
ngOnInit() {
    this.httpservice.getdata().subscribe
    (data=>
    {
     this.MyArray.push(data);

     console.log(MyArray[0][1].name);
    });
}
```

If you want to access outside of service method, you must be sure the service function has loaded the data.

You can wait for it like this:

```
private MyArray: any[] = [];

private IsDataLoaded: boolean = false;

ngOnInit() {
    this.httpservice.getdata().subscribe
    (data=>
    {
     this.MyArray.push(data);
     IsDataLoaded = true;
    });
}

while(true) {
    if(IsDataLoaded) {
        break;
    }
}

// Or this
//while(!IsDataLoaded) {
//    // do nothing but wait
//}

console.log(MyArray[0][1].name);
```

Comment: I tried this. But the array is not being assigned the data using this method. I am just getting an empty array.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have made the necessary edits in the question. How can I access it from outside?

Comment: @mistletoe I've updated my answer. You should wait till data loads.

Comment: I tried this but my chrome just kept on loading. I had to forcefully close this using task manager.

Comment: You should be sure service has timeout and on any error skip the while part. Otherwise you get a deadlock.